# How to bring forward an object in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object

I've a simple project with a few objects.
I tried to move "player" object ([Marked in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzYX4.jpg)) to top of other objects but still it is in backward!
How to bring it to forward?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what code you've tried, as per site rules.

Comment: Putting it at the top of the herarchy does not make it nearer. It means it’s made first so actually puts it by default further away or you could look the 2d layers as this seems to be 2d but this is documented well by unity

Answer (score 1):

We need some more information to give an accurate answer for your exact situation, such as the properties of the Sprite Renderer (assuming Player is a sprite) and the properties of your Canvas and UI elements (especially if it is a world space canvas), and any code you might be using to instantiate, render, or move the player.

In general though, for sprites, you can bring a sprite in front of other sprites by either changing the Z value of the transform (negative Z is closer to the camera), or better by changing the Order in Layer of the player sprite renderer, and make sure it is in a layer that is in front of the other sprites.

As for Canvas UI elements, the element at the bottom of the hierarchy will be rendered last, meaning it will show in front of everything.  Think of a UI hierarchy like stacking papers on top of each other.  The first piece of paper placed down will be at the bottom of the pile.